# Email signature creator

Tags: windows, email, outlook

I'm looking for signature generator for Outlook.

We have 20+ users, each average have 3 email addresses. I need something that allows me to create and edit signatures (already I'm doing this by creating one, copy and editing).

This what I found online, are priced by mailbox, cloudbase.

I need something what I can install under Windows.

Comment: And what's wrong with default Outlook signatures? What's wrong with them?

Comment: @thims nothing is wrong, simply when you have 20+ users and 5+ domains you need something to organise and create. Also our signatures will changing so it's very difficult to do this with outlook

Answer (score 1):

You have a very good solution with [CodeTwo](https://www.codetwo.com/email-signatures-for-email-clients/) and his WYSIWYG editor.
Other features are:

- Unified but containing personal information at the same time
- Signatures is displayed while composing an email. Displayed while composing an email message
- Easily add images and banners Equipped with social media icons, hyperlinks, and visuals
- Adjust and control themes and stationery, message format, categories and font formating. Adjusted to your company standards as it controls themes and stationery, message format, categories and font formatting

Other possible solution is [newoldstamp](https://newoldstamp.com/) also with social links and icons, templates, Dashboard + central management, banner buttons, etc.