# Email Signature Manager

Tags: outlook, signature

One of my jobs in the company I work with is to make sure everyone has the correct up to date email signature. Every time we update our signature, I have to create the updated ones, and then deploy them. Creating them is not an issue, it doesn't take long. But deploying them is another question altogether, as I have to remote on to all the machines (I don't have physical access to all).

I deploy the email signatures by copying the `.htm`, `.txt`, and `.rtf` into the `User/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Signatures` folder.

So I'm looking for the best solution for this, which could come in one of three forms:

- A signature manager, specifically designed for this.
- A plugin for Outlook
- A mutli-computer file syncing program

Or if you can suggest a better solution please do.

A couple of points:

- All machines are running Windows 10 Pro & Outlook 2013 or 2016
- Preferably [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), or lowish cost (I'm looking to make my job easier, so I will be paying for this, not the company)

I did find this question ([Email signature creator](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32366/email-signature-creator)) on here, but it's more about creating them, and also does not have an answer.

Comment: Tools exist such as [Rocketseed](https://www.rocketseed.com/products/email-signatures/) but their pricing is on your request.

Comment: My work place puts all kinds of notices at the bottom/top of outgoing emails, server side.  No reason your users couldn't simply have their constant info (name, email, phone, whatever) followed by a server-added corporate block....

Comment: what is the problem here? how to copy the correct file to these destinations?

Comment: @svetlana no, how to copy multiple files to multiple different machines, without having to do it manually. Right now I have to remote onto each employee's machine, and manually copy the files of their new signature across. I'd like something that does that automatically for me.

Comment: does the powershell solution below work for you?

Comment: @svetlana not in it's current form, no. The computers aren't all on the same subnet, so can't just target them like that. I potentially could do something with OneDrive, where I put the file in our company wide OneDrive folder, and then a script runs daily to copy that to the signature file, but I'm not clued up enough to figure that out

Answer (score 1):

If you really just need to push the file to several computers, then maybe a PowerShell script to do exactly that would be enough?

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName TargetMachine -Credential $cred
Copy-Item -Path C:\localfile.txt -Destination C:\remotefile.txt -ToSession $session
```

This needs PowerShell 5, apparently. And you probably want a loop of some sort to do it for all the target machines.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use a *Text Expander* tool.

In my case [espanso](https://espanso.org/) is a perfect solution:

- Cross-platform
- Shell support
- Custom scripts
- Emoji/html/markdown support
- Open-source license